# postgreSQL how to run a function for every tupple of a table?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with 5 different tupples and I want to call a function for every row. I tried with for-loop but there is something wrong with the code.
First of all I want to call the function with the fid (first column of temp) for every row 
Also I have return next r in comment because I get an error: cannot use RETURN NEXT in a non-SETOF function.
My function returns void

```
CREATE TABLE temp3(fid numeric,des numeric,distribution numeric,code numeric,price real,fprogr numeric ,datef date);

insert into temp3(fid,des,distribution,code,price,fprogr,datef)
SELECT id,dest, count(*),fc,price,progr,fdate  
FROM tableA; 

FOR r IN SELECT * FROM temp3
WHERE temp3.fid > 0
LOOP                  
select * from u_flight2(fid);
-- RETURN NEXT r; -- return current row of SELECT
END LOOP;
```

Comment: What version of Postgres are you using?

Comment: So what does `u_flight2()` do?

Comment: u_flight2 inserts some tupples in a table also returns void

Answer (score 3):

In Postgres 9.3 and later you can use the `LATERAL` keyword (described [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-LATERAL)):

```
select u.*
from temp3 t,
     lateral u_flight2(t.fid) u;
```